# Why can I get and API data with fetch and not with Axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

I got this test code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const readWithAxios = async (basicAuth, user, passwd) => {
    let options = {
        auth: {
            username: user,
            password: passwd
        },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        withCredentials: true
    };

    return axios.get('https:///geolite.info/geoip/v2.1/country/me?pretty', options);
}

const readWithFetch = (basicAuth) => {
    return new Promise(res=>{
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Authorization', basicAuth);

        fetch('https://geolite.info/geoip/v2.1/country/me?pretty', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers,
        }).then(response => res(response.json()));
    })
}

const readData = async () => {
    let user = '<my_api_user>';
    let passwd = '<my_api_key>';
    let basicAuth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(user + ":" + passwd).toString('base64');

    let geoData;

    //geoData = await readWithFetch(basicAuth);
    geoData = await readWithAxios(basicAuth, user, passwd);

    console.log(geoData);
}
readData();
```

I'm trying to understand why readWithFetch works fine and axios gets connection refused. It's a simple basic auth... nothing fancy.

I've tried all these readWithAxios versions:

#### Version 1

```
const readWithAxios = async (basicAuth, user, passwd) => {
    let options = {
        auth: {
            username: user,
            password: passwd
        },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        withCredentials: true
    };

    console.log('options', options);
    return axios.get('https:///geolite.info/geoip/v2.1/country/me?pretty', options);
}
```

#### Version 2

```
const readWithAxios = async (basicAuth, user, passwd) => {
    let options = {
        auth: {
            username: user,
            password: passwd
        },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", 'Authorization': basicAuth},
        withCredentials: true
    };

    console.log('options', options);
    return axios.get('https:///geolite.info/geoip/v2.1/country/me?pretty', options);
}
```

#### Version 3

```
const readWithAxios = async (basicAuth, user, passwd) => {
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https:///geolite.info/geoip/v2.1/country/me?pretty',
        auth: {
            username: user,
            password: passwd
        },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", 'Authorization': basicAuth},
        withCredentials: true
    };
```

#### Version 4

```
    return axios(options);
}

const readWithAxios = async (basicAuth, user, passwd) => {
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https:///geolite.info/geoip/v2.1/country/me?pretty',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", 'Authorization': basicAuth},
        withCredentials: true
    };

    return axios(options);
}
```

What is the correct way to write *readWithAxios*?

Comment: What are the HTTP responses? Axios `withCredentials` is used to send cookies.

Comment: All the examples I have seen have used the `auth` option by itself without the `withCredentials` option.

Comment: @OFRBG ECONNREFUSED,

Comment: @Geshode I tried without `WithCredentials` and the result was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a triple slash in `https:///geolite` in the Axios versions. It should be `https://`

Comment: OH MY GOD... I lost like 2h in this one! LOL Jesus!

Comment: Tim Berners-Lee regrets adding // https://archive.nytimes.com/bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/10/12/the-webs-inventor-regrets-one-small-thing/

Comment: Wow, good spot.